# Can you rename your ship?

Tags: helldivers-2

After completing the tutorial in Helldivers 2, you are asked to name your ship. Is it possible to rename your ship later on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can rename your ship at the computers to the left of your ship hangar where you spawn in your ship after a mission. Walk up to a computer, interact with it, then select "Change Ship Name".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

According to [Gamesradar](https://www.gamesradar.com/helldivers-2-change-ship-name/), you can at the ship management console:

> To give your Helldivers 2 ship a new name, start by opening one of the Ship Management consoles in the hangar area. Next, click the "Change Ship Name" button on the right of the screen (Square on PlayStation) to bring up the full range of name options, letting you choose an entirely new name.